# Data structure and algorithms: Should one use OOP to program algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, oop, data-structures

I have seen people code for example, say a quicksort algorithm without using OOP. I have also seen the identical algorithm in Robert Lafore's data structure and algorithm textbook written under OOP framework. 
Is it better to do it using OOP  ? What are the advantages or disadvantages?

Suppose I know how to write an algorithm in both ways, should I always do it the OOP way ? Or does it depend on the algorithm itself ? If yes, then what algorithms would using OOP be beneficial ?